# .htaccess for redirecting languages in php app

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multingual website. In PHP, I'm making all the pages have unique id, so that I know which files to include. All the logic is going through index.php page.

So, I'd like to have montkuce.com/en/foobar to send a request to index.php via GET like this: index.php?id=foobar&lang=en

This is what I have so far, and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://montkuce.com/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://montkuce.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://montkuce.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://montkuce.com/it/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://montkuce.com/cz/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^sk [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://montkuce.com/sk/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|it|cz|sk)/(.*)$/?$ index.php?lang=$1&id=2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is little off in the last rule. Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|it|cz|sk)/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&id=2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. It takes me to montkuce.com/en/lang=en and it fails to load everything else.

Comment: No this rule doesn't do any redirect so URL won't change by this rule. You may have some other rules also. Do you have any other .htaccess anywhere?

Comment: I changed the last line to say:

RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|it|cz|sk)/(.*?)/?$ http://montkuce.com/index.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

But now it redirects montkuce.com/en/foobar to montkuce.com/index.php?lang=en&id=foobar

which is basically what I want, except that I want original URL to stay in location bar of my browser

Comment: No you cannot do that. If you use `http://` in target URI then rule will start redirecting instead of rewriting. Keep your rule as I have shown above.

Comment: If I do that it won't load my css files.

Comment: Oh for that just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. OR You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`